# Backbone.js model.save() sending multiple PUT requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I have a backbone view that loads a model and some templates. When I submit the form in the edit template, backbone successfully sends a PUT request, just as it’s supposed to. On success, I navigate the user back to the view template.

However, if I navigate to the edit route again and submit the form, backbone sends *two* PUT requests. It then GETs the view template. If I navigate to the edit route a third time, backbone sends *three* PUT requests. The number of PUT requests keep incrementing every time I submit the form. Why might that be?

Here is my view:

```
// Filename views/users/edit.js
/*global define:false */

define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/user/UserModel',
    'text!templates/users/edit.html',
], function($, _, Backbone, UserModel, UserTemplate) {

    var UserEdit = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#page',
        render: function (options) {

            var that = this;

            if (options.id) {
                // modify existing user
                var user = new UserModel({id: options.id});
                user.fetch({
                    success: function (user) {
                        var template = _.template(UserTemplate, {user: user});
                        that.$el.animate({opacity: 0}, 180, function() {
                            that.$el.html(template).animate({opacity: 1}, 180);
                        });
                    }
                });
            } else {
                // create new user
                var template = _.template(UserTemplate, {user: null});
                that.$el.animate({opacity: 0}, 180, function() {
                    that.$el.html(template).animate({opacity: 1}, 180);
                });
            }

        },
        events: {
            'submit #create-user-form': 'createUser'
        },
        createUser: function (e) {
            var postData = $(e.currentTarget).serializeObject();
            var user = new UserModel();
            user.save(postData, {
            success: function (user, response) {
                Backbone.history.navigate('#/users/view/' + response, {trigger: true, replace: true});
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });

    return UserEdit;

});
```

Comment: Quick thought, do you undelegate the UserEdit view after you assign/create a new one? See Derick Bailey's [post](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/) on this

Comment: Since I’m not sure, I’m going to say “No” :)

Comment: to continue with where @dbf is going, I would add console.log in createUser function, see if it gets called twice

Comment: @ekeren That’s what I tried first to debug. createUser was indeed getting called an additional time, each time.

Comment: @dbf The post you linked to illustrates exactly the behaviour I’m experiencing, and now I understand more about why it’s happening. So, thanks for that!

Comment: @dbf: In my case backbone is sending post request multiple times despite of adding `that.undelegateEvents()` in success callback of backbone `save`. Any idea, why does this happen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my case, I could fix it by calling `undelegateEvents()` on the view in the success callback.

```
createUser: function (e) {
    var postData = $(e.currentTarget).serializeObject(),
            user = new UserModel(),
            that = this;

    user.save(postData, {
        success: function (user, response) {
            that.undelegateEvents();
            Backbone.history.navigate('#/users/view/' + response, {trigger: true});
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

Thanks, @dbf.

Comment: In my case backbone is sending post request multiple times despite of adding `that.undelegateEvents()` in success callback of backbone `save`. Any idea, why does this happen?

Comment: @user2235057 What did you bind `that` to?

Comment: I have binded it to the current backbone view.